# all possible permutations of digits in a given number

Tags: arrays, algorithm, database-design, loops, discrete-mathematics

The user should input how many digits are in his number, and then he should input his number. The code should then arrange that number in all possible ways, without recursion.

For example the number 123 can be arranged in 6 ways:

123 132
213 231
312 321

Just a side note, if there is something wrong about the way I asked this question, or if more information is required, please please please let me know. Even if you do not know the answer to my question. I really need to get this question answered, I think I'm starting to go insane over it.

Comment: If the number is `101`, do you want the two different `110` answers to count as different permutations?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow .Please show your effort in question instead of asking question and expecting answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to generating all permutations.

```
For generating the next permutation after the current one(the first one is 123):
  1. Find from right to left the first position pos where current[pos] < current[pos + 1]
  2. Increment current[pos] to the next possible number(some numbers are maybe already used)
  3. At the remaining positions(> pos) put the smallest possible numbers not used.
  4. Go to 1.
```

Here is a working code, printing all permutations:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int n = 3;

        int[] current = new int[n];
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            current[i - 1] = i;
        }

        int total = 0;
        for (;;) {
            total++;

            boolean[] used = new boolean[n + 1];
            Arrays.fill(used, true);

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.print(current[i] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();

            used[current[n - 1]] = false;

            int pos = -1;
            for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {              
                used[current[i]] = false;

                if (current[i] < current[i + 1]) {
                    pos = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (pos == -1) {
                break;
            }               

            for (int i = current[pos] + 1; i <= n; i++) {
                if (!used[i]) {
                    current[pos] = i;
                    used[i] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                if (!used[i]) {
                    current[++pos] = i;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(total);
    }       
}
```

P.S. I wrote the code just now in a couple of minutes. I don't claim that the code is clean or the variables are named good.

Comment: AARGH! a GOTO! panic!

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of [googling](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=permutation+algorithm) around and you will find some algorithms, for example the [Johnson-Trotter Algorithm](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Combinatorics/JohnsonTrotter.shtml) which can be described in 5 lines:

```
Initialize the first permutation with <1 <2 ... <n
while there exists a mobile integer
  find the largest mobile integer k
  swap k and the adjacent integer it is looking at
  reverse the direction of all integers larger than k
```